# Show the current time in input and the time before greyed out

Tags: javascript, html

I want the current time in

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="uhrzeit_beginn" name="uhrzeit_beginn" required>
```

and the time before the current should be greyed out. I tried it with min and max in JS but it dosen't work in google chrome.

And is it possible that two times do not overlap?

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: What did you try writing inside your min?

Comment: the current time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147025/have-time-automatically-be-in-the-input-type-time

Comment: with that solution i can still click the time befor the current time

Comment: so you want to grey out the field if i enter 12:20 and current system time is 15:23? else show the normal field?